# Invalid Metadata Requests on Google Compute Engine

Tags: http, metadata, google-compute-engine

I am running a Google Compute Engine instance.  About every ten seconds, I get a request from a local link address (such as `169.254.169.254`) requesting metadata from my instance.   The request is on the `computeMetadata` path, suggesting that google is trying an [to get meta data from my instance].

Why am I receiving these requests? Do I have compute engine configured incorrectly?  Right now my app returns a 404, should it do something else?

This is the full request:

```
010.240.059.243.48574-169.254.169.254.00080: GET /computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/network-interfaces/0/public-endpoint-ips?alt=text&wait_for_change=true&timeout_sec=60&last_etag=NONE HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: metadata
Connection: close
User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

The images provided by default on GCE will automatically configure themselves based on data returned by the [metadata server](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata).

This particular request is to find IPs that are forwarded to this instance as part of [Load Balancing](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/).  Basically, the script at `/usr/share/google/google_daemon/manage_addresses.py` will continually wait for new IP addresses to be forwarded to this instance.  Once it notices a new incoming IP (as indicated by the metadata server) it will configure the instances network stack to respond to that IP.

The question in my mind is: why are you seeing these?  Are you doing something interesting to capture the requests sent to that address?  These should be completely transparent to any application.

Comment: My question is the same as yours! I understand that these requests are usually handled by the metadata server. However, my GCE instance is (hopefully!) not a metadata server.  I am doing nothing to intentionally capture these requests. I am only running a python/django instance with a few other services.  I should not be seeing these requests and I'm afraid this may be part of a bigger problem (I've noticed hanging on this instance).  If you the name of the instance, please email me at michael dot sander at gmail.